# File I/O Concept

Tags: java, file, io

I'm new in java. My assignment requires using the File I/O Concept
The Problem Is when I run the code for the second time, it makes the file new and the clear, I want to write the new data with the old data each other.
any idea ?

and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Please post the relevant part of your code so we know how you're opening the file.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: Never hurts to go to the [source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Both [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) and [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) have a constructor taking a `boolean append` as argument. Use this constructor with `append` set to true.

Reading the javadoc helps finding the solution for simple problems like that. Java also has a tutorial for almost everything. Google for *someSubject Java tutorial*, and you'll find them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May you tell me How I Can reset a scanner to the beginning of a file?

Comment: You recreate a new one on top of a new input stream.